# Find the maximum integer $a$ such that $2 <\log_{4}{a} < \log_{2}{7}$

Tags: inequality

Short of just plugging in values of $a$ and seeing what works, I don't know how to solve this systematically. How do you find $a$ and what is the name of this type of problem so I can learn about it?

Comment: if I knew what ST meant I'd try to help. edit: such that I would just use   ":"

Comment: Thanks for correction. Forgot that English is not everyones first language. Suppose I have gotten used to this convention cause of my university

Comment: it's not that English isn't my first language, it's that I haven't seen it written that way before.

Comment: Sorry for assuming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$2 < \log_4 a < \log_2 7$$

$$4^2 < a < 4^{\log_2 7}$$

$$4^2 < a < 2^{2\log_2 7}$$

$$4^2 < a < 2 ^ {\log_2 7^2}$$

$$4^2 < a < 7^2$$